# Custom font is displayed weird

Tags: css, fonts

From the start I need to say that I know what I'm trying to do is not "the right way to do it", but the client I'm working for desperately wants THIS specific font.

So, I need to use on a client's website the exact font as VOGUE uses. So I took the .eot & .ttf and uploaded them on my server. Then I added the CSS definitions:

```
/*fonts fonts for IE*/
@font-face {
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "VogueDidot Light";
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*fonts for other browsers*/
@font-face {
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "VogueDidot Light";
    src: url('font/FBDidotL-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And the CSS for my element is:

```
.post h1 {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: VogueDidot;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 58px;
}
```

And, normally, I expected to see everything working like a charm.

But it's not...

Here's how it should look like:

https://lh.rs/8M9Q7EvRBapv

And here's my version :

https://lh.rs/Lbini5YbQZlX

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that using custom fonts are not pixel perfect on all browsers since all browsers tend to render the fonts differently. Another issue can be people not enabling ClearType within windows which I'm sure in this case its not but for other readers I decided to include this information.

It would seem that your font support is pretty limited since you are only using .ttf and .eot - for maximum compatibly and limiting render issues it's best to use 'ALL' 5 font types which are:

- ttf (TrueType Font)
- oft (Adobe/Microsoft Open Font Type, AKA OpenType)
- eot (Embedded OpenType)
- woff (Web Open Font Format)
- svg (Scalable Vector Graphics)

Ideally you want to use SVG as much as you can since this provides the best quality, SVG is supported in modern versions of Andriod Browser, Firefix, Safari, Opera, Chrome but not in IE.

Personally I'd convert the fonts to all these file types and see if the outcome improves, browsers will automatically use their preferred font type. You can use [Font 2 Web](http://www.font2web.com/) to convert to the other formats, its important to note that fonts are copyrighted and your client will require licensing, some fonts don't even allow web use.